# Testing with Java Protocol notations for URLConnection

Tags: java

Where can I get all the details about the protocols we can use in java to make a URL connection.
like : for jar its jar:file:///c|/!/ what does this notaion mean ?
what wd be for let's say nntp, telnet or ftp kind of protocols. does sun provides any documentation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that is fixed is the specification laid out in RFC3986 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-1.1.1) . For the different protocols Java uses differen `java.net.URLStreamHandler`s. These are found dynamically at runtime 
You can even register a custom `URLStramHandlerFactory` for own protocols. The different handlers are chosen dynamically when using `URL.openConnection()`

Default handlers available in JDK are in sub-packages of `sun.net.www.protocol` and classes are named Handler, i.e. `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler` is for jar protocol and `sun.net.www.protocol.mailto.Handler` is for mailto. 
Available protocols are:

- FTP
- jar
- netdoc
- file
- gopher
- mailto
- http
- https

For each of the protocols the according RFC specifies the exact URI syntax

Answer (score -1):

[`URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) has two direct subclasses:

- [JarURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html)
- [HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

All you need is look into the javadoc (links above).

Comment: URLConnection still allows more protocols than those two sub classes.